# OccupancyGridUpdate.h file cannot found

Tags: ros, navigation, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I launch catkin_make, I got this error "erreur fatale: map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate.h : Any file of this kind"
However in map-msgs/src the file OccupancyGridUpdate.h is here.
So what is the error
I'm using groovy

**Edit this is the CMakeLists :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(costmap_2d)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  eigen
  geometry_msgs
  laser_geometry
  map_server
  nav_msgs
  pcl
  pcl_ros
  rosbag
  rosconsole
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  visualization_msgs
  voxel_grid
  message_generation
  map_msgs
)


find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})


add_message_files(
    DIRECTORY msg
    FILES
    VoxelGrid.msg
)

generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
        std_msgs
        geometry_msgs
        
)

# dynamic reconfigure
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/Costmap2D.cfg
  cfg/ObstaclePlugin.cfg
  cfg/GenericPlugin.cfg
  cfg/InflationPlugin.cfg
  cfg/VoxelPlugin.cfg
)



include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
        ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    LIBRARIES costmap_2d
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
        dynamic_reconfigure
        geometry_msgs
        laser_geometry
        nav_msgs
        pcl_ros
        roscpp
        sensor_msgs
        std_msgs
        tf
        voxel_grid
    DEPENDS
        PCL
        Eigen
        Boost
)


add_library(costmap_2d
  src/array_parser.cpp
  src/costmap_2d.cpp
  src/observation_buffer.cpp
  src/layer.cpp
  src/layered_costmap.cpp
  src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp
  src/costmap_2d_publisher.cpp
  src/costmap_math.cpp
  src/footprint.cpp
  src/costmap_layer.cpp
)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d geometry_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(layers
  plugins/footprint_layer.cpp
  plugins/inflation_layer.cpp
  plugins/obstacle_layer.cpp
  plugins/static_layer.cpp
  plugins/voxel_layer.cpp
  src/observation_buffer.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(layers
  costmap_2d
)

add_dependencies(costmap_2d costmap_2d_gencfg)
add_dependencies(layers costmap_2d_gencfg)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d costmap_2d_gencpp)

add_executable(costmap_2d_markers src/costmap_2d_markers.cpp)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d_markers visualization_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_markers
    costmap_2d
    )

add_executable(costmap_2d_cloud src/costmap_2d_cloud.cpp)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d_cloud sensor_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_cloud
    costmap_2d
    )

add_executable(costmap_2d_node src/costmap_2d_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_node
    costmap_2d
    )

## Configure Tests
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  # Find package test dependencies
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  find_package(gtest)

  # Add the test folder to the include directories
  include_directories(test)

  include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${GTEST_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  # Create targets for test executables
  add_executable(costmap_tester EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/costmap_tester.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests costmap_tester)
  target_link_libraries(costmap_tester costmap_2d ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(footprint_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/footprint_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests footprint_tests)
  target_link_libraries(footprint_tests costmap_2d ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(obstacle_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/obstacle_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests obstacle_tests)
  target_link_libraries(obstacle_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(static_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/static_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests static_tests)
  target_link_libraries(static_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(inflation_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/inflation_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests inflation_tests)
  target_link_libraries(inflation_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  catkin_download_test_data(${PROJECT_NAME}_simple_driving_test_indexed.bag
    http://download.ros.org/data/costmap_2d/simple_driving_test_indexed.bag
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test
    MD5 61168cff9425b11e093ea3a627c81c8d)
  catkin_download_test_data(${PROJECT_NAME}_willow-full-0.025.pgm
    http://download.ros.org/data/costmap_2d/willow-full-0.025.pgm
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test
    MD5 e66b17ee374f2d7657972efcb3e2e4f7)

  add_rostest(test/footprint_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/inflation_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/obstacle_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/simple_driving_test.xml)
  add_rostest(test/static_tests.launch)

  catkin_add_gtest(array_parser_test test/array_parser_test.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(array_parser_test costmap_2d)
endif()

install( TARGETS
    costmap_2d_markers
    costmap_2d_cloud
    costmap_2d_node
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS
    costmap_2d
    layers
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES costmap_plugins.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187039/occupancygridupdate.h-file-cannot-found/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-18**:
Can you post your CMakeLists.txt? You are probably just missing something in the include_directories() call.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
Sorry I can upload a file (I don't have enough Karma). I copied the contents of the file in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add "map_msgs" to find_package catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS in `CMakeLists` and `build_depend`, `run_depend` in `package.xml`

```
<build_depend>map_msgs</build_depend>
 <run_depend>map_msgs</run_depend>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  eigen
  geometry_msgs
  laser_geometry
  map_server
  nav_msgs
  pcl
  pcl_ros
  rosbag
  rosconsole
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  visualization_msgs
  voxel_grid
  message_generation
  map_msgs
)
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
No sorry, It doesn't work

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
add "map_msgs" in CATKIN_DEPENDS and generate_messages DEPENDENCIES also

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
I don't understand. Should I add map_msgs in generate_messages?
If i do so i got this error

**Could not find 'share/map_msgs/cmake/map_msgs-msg-paths.cmake' (searched in
'/home/lempereur/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/groovy').**

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
yes you need to add in generate_messages.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
Thank you!!!!!
I had a similar error, i posted in a new question, please help me